# Could "ω is an ordinal" be proved without axiom of induction?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let ω (or all natural numbers) be the set defined by the axiom of infinity in ZF system, ordinal be "transitive and well ordered by ∈", and a set is transitive if all its elements are also its subset.

It seems that induction is now extended to base on ordinal and could be proved, so it's no longer an axiom. ω is considered the smallest part of ordinals, this needs to be proved. And to prove the old induction based on integer, it's also necessary to prove that ω is an ordinal, of cause without using the old axiom of induction. Is it possible ?

To prove directly ω is transitive, it's necessary to prove that all elements of ω are subset of ω. We know that Ø is subset of ω, and for any element n of ω, if n is subset of ω then its successor n⋃{n} is a subset of ω. But from this to "all element of ω is subset of ω", we need old axiom of induction.

If in another way, to prove that ω is an initial segment of ordinals, we need to prove that all elements of ω are ordinal. We know that Ø is an ordinal, and for any element n of ω, if n is an ordinal then its successor n⋃{n} is an ordinal. But from this to prove "all elements of ω are ordinal", we need also the old axiom of induction.

How to prove that ω is an ordinal without using the old axiom of induction ?

Comment: There is no "axiom of induction" in ZF (hence any theorem of ZF can be proved without it).

Comment: While @DavidC.Ullrich is right, there is a subtlety to this question that often gets overlooked. It may turn out that $\omega$ - the least indutive set - contains non-standard natural numbers that are not of the form $0$ or $n \cup \{n\}$ for some $n \in \omega$. Is this the point of your question? (Most likely, it's not. But in doubt...)

Comment: You cannot prove anything about $\omega$ without defining it. Which def'n of $\omega$ are you starting from?

Comment: The existence of an infinite set is the subject of the Axiom of Infinity in ZFC (and similar foundations).  It is possible to define $\omega$ in such a way that its existence follows from the Axiom of Infinity (and other axioms of ZFC), and then be able to prove its well-orderedness or transitivity of set membership, depending on how "ordinal" is defined in your approach.  Please clarify both the definition of $\omega$ and of 
"ordinal".

Comment: The definition of ω is: Ø is an element of ω, if n is an element of ω then n⋃{n} is also an element of ω. According to this definition, Ø is an element of ω; {Ø}=Ø⋃{Ø} is an element of ω; {Ø,{Ø}}={Ø}⋃{{Ø}} is an element of ω; {Ø,{Ø},{Ø,{Ø}}}={Ø,{Ø}}⋃{{Ø,{Ø}}} is an element of ω; .... In a clearer notation, if we note Ø by 0, {Ø} by 1, {Ø,{Ø}} by 2, {Ø,{Ø},{Ø,{Ø}}} by 3, then the integer n+1 will denote n⋃{n}, we shall get 0=Ø, 1={0}, 2={0,1}, 3={0,1,2}, 4={0,1,2,3}, ... n+1={0,1,2,...,n}. ω is the set of all sets denoted by integer as above no exception.

Comment: So, no element in ω has the form different from n⋃{n} except Ø.

Comment: Axiom of induction is not part of set theory. It's based on integer as we learn in high school. Perhaps what you learn is not an axiom and is proved by "there is the minimal element in any set of natural numbers". In this case, this minimal value principal is an axiom. But in set theory, ω is an ordinal is not an axiom, so it should be proved. So, the minimal value principal could not be used here. That's why I treat the induction of high school an axiom. It's an axiom in peano's definition of natural number.

Comment: @user49413: You cannot do induction or recursive constructions without having ordinals in the first place. You are constructing $\omega$ by a recursive procedure along $\omega$. That is a circular definition.

Comment: tomasz: ordinal is defined by property. ω is defined by construction. They are independent. It's the link between them that is necessary to be proved here.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use the axiom of induction to prove that $\omega$ is an ordinal. We prove it based on the definition of $\omega$.

First, the definition of $\omega$ is that it is the smallest inductive set. That is, it is a set I such that $\emptyset \in I$ and for all $x \in I$, $x \cup \{ x \} \in I$, and such that if $J$ satisfies those, then $I \subseteq J$.

First we show that $\omega$ is transitive. Let $T = \{ n \in \omega : n \subseteq \omega \}$. Clearly if $T = \omega$ then $\omega$ is transitive. We show that $T$ is inductive. First $\emptyset \in T$ by definition. Then if $x \in T$, then $x \subseteq \omega$ and $x \in \omega$, therefore $x \cup \{ x \} \subseteq \omega$, so $x \cup \{ x \} \in T$. Hence $T$ is inductive and therefore $T = \omega$.

Now there are a couple of things we can show. Most commonly, we would show that $\in$ is a well order on $\omega$. Another equivalent definition (in the presence of the axiom of foundation) of an ordinal is a transitive set of transitive sets, this may be easier to show. So we let $T = \{ n \in \omega : \forall x \in n \: x \subseteq n \}$. Then again, we wish to show that $T = \omega$, and we do so by showing that $T$ is inductive. $\emptyset \in T$ again vacuously. If $n \in T$, then let $x \in n \cup \{ n \}$. Either $x \in n$, and therefore $x \subseteq n \implies x \subseteq n \cup \{ n \}$, or $x = n$, and therefore $x \subseteq n \cup \{ n \}$. Hence $T$ is inductive so again $T = \omega$, and therefore $\omega$ is a transitive set of transitive sets.

Comment: The axiom of infinity guarantees the existence of induction set. How to prove the existence of the smallest induction set ? In this way, the existence of ω itself will be a question. T⊆ω is OK. T is an inductive set is also OK. So, the problem is ω is the smallest. Unless to modify the axiom of infinity to "there exist unique set so that ..." ?

Comment: Inductive set is not unique because all limit ordinals are inductive set. But the constructed set with Ø and all the successors could be unique.

Comment: OK, I understand now. The axiom of infinity claims the existence of inductive set. Inductive set is not unique. Any limit ordinal is an inductive set. Let A be one of inductive set. Consider the property P(x)=∀E((E is inductive)→(x∈E)). ω is the set defined by P(x) in A. Then ω is the intersection of all inductive sets. We can prove that ω is inductive. So ω is the smallest inductive set. We can prove, by knowledge on ordinal, that Ø is an ordinal; if n is an ordinal then n∪{n} is an ordinal. Consider property P'(x)=(x is an ordinal). The set defined by P'(x) in ω is inductive.

Comment: So, the set defined by P'(x) in ω is ω itself. That is, all elements of ω is ordinal. We can prove that ω is an initial segment of ordinals. So ω is an ordinal by knowledge on ordinal.

Comment: In general, if a property P''(x) satisfies the condition of induction, that is, P''(Ø) is TRUE, for any n∈ω, P''(n)→P''(n∪{n}), then the set defined by P''(x) in ω is inductive so is ω itself. So, all elements of ω has P''(x). The old axiom of induction is proved so is no longer an axiom. Thanks to Athar Abdul-Quader.